# Need help and Want to know how we can write this type of Neo4j Cypher query into Gremlin query?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

```
MATCH (m:movie)-[has_directed_by:has_directed]->(director:Director)

OPTIONAL MATCH(director)-[has_name:has_name]->(directorName:DirectorName)

OPTIONAL MATCH(director)-[has_type:has_type]->(directionType:DirectionType)

OPTIONAL MATCH(director)-[has_language:has_language]->(directionLanguage:DirectionLangugaue)

OPTIONAL MATCH (director)-[has_script:has_script]->(script:Script) 

OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[has_songs:has_songs]->(songs:Songs)

WITH m,has_directed_by,director,has_name,directorName,has_type,directionType,
has_language,directionLanguage,has_script,script order by m.id ASC 

RETURN distinct m,collect(has_directed_by),collect(director),collect(has_name),
collect(directorName),collect(has_type),collect(directionType),collect(has_language),collect(directionLanguage),collect(has_script),collect(script),collect(has_songs),collect(songs);
```

How to write a gremlin query for this type of hard queries in cypher?
Please help! I wanted to know how can we refer to that 'm' and 'director' again and again in the gremlin.

Example:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('movie').as('m').
  outE('has_directed').
  inV().
  hasLabel('Director').as('director')
```

But need to refer to that 'm' and 'director' in the upcoming traversal of the graph. Please help

Comment: Hello. I see you took our discussion from the Apache TinkerPop Discord and moved it to Stack Overflow. You will find on Stack Overflow that people will expect you to have had a first attempt at writing the query/code . Otherwise the question is likely to  get closed by a moderator. I have added a fairly detailed answer below with several suggestions on how to convert your Cypher query to Gremlin.  Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, no pun intended, for conversions like this it's best to take it one step at a time. The first line is roughly equivalent to:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('movie').as('m').
  outE('has_directed').
  inV().
  hasLabel('Director').as('director')
```

However, it's often possible to use more idiomatic Gremlin that avoids a lot of `as` steps using an approach built around a step such as `project`. You only need the `outE` and `inV` steps if you need to retrieve properties from the edge. Otherwise just `out` will suffice.

Gremlin also has a `match` step that would allow you to convert the Cypher query in a similar, declarative style, but I prefer to use other Gremlin steps and avoid `match` in most cases.

In Gremlin there is an `optional` step but there are also the `coalesce` and `choose` steps that allows you to write a sort of `IF...THEN...ELSE` type of query which is equivalent to `OPTIONAL MATCH`

In terms of `distinct` the equivalent Gremlin step is `dedup`

One way in Gremlin to combine a selection of optional things together is to use a `union` step.

The `fold` step in Gremlin can be used in a similar way to the `collect` step in Cypher.

As I do not have your data set, I used the air-routes data set to demonstrate the equivalent of an `OPTIONAL MATCH` essentially using a `fold` step to generate an empty list when there are no results.

```java
gremlin>   g.V('0','44').
......1>     project('start','neighbors').
......2>       by(id).
......3>       by(out().fold())

==>[start:0,neighbors:[]]
==>[start:44,neighbors:[v[8],v[13],v[20],v[31]]]
```

As mentioned above the `fold` step is similar to the Cypher `collect` function. In the example above, when there is no match, the neighbors are represented by an empty list. You can have as many sub parts (key name and `by` modulator) for a `project` step as needed to represent all of your optional cases.

There are of course many ways to write the query depending on how you wish to represent the case where nothing was found. If you prefer to have a default value rather than an empty list you can use a `coalesce` step.

```java
gremlin>  g.V('0','44').
......1>     project('start','neighbors').
......2>       by(id).
......3>       by(coalesce(out(),constant('None')))

==>[start:0,neighbors:None]
==>[start:44,neighbors:v[8]]
```

Using a similar pattern with your data set, the basic building blocks might be:

```java
 g.V().
    hasLabel('Movie').
    project('movie','director').
      by(valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)).
      by(out('has_directed').valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens).fold())
```

The `valueMap` step will return all of the properties for a vertex (or edge). I added that to my example to simulate what Cypher will do. By default (without a step like `valueMap`) Gremlin will just return the vertex without its properties in many cases. The `with` tells Gremlin to also include the ID and label in the results. This is equivalent to the deprecated form `valueMap(true)`.